# Making a discord.py bot use external commands

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm planning to make an all-purpose bot, where it can call other bots too. Any ideas?

```py
import os
import discord
import time
from discord.ext import commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

TOKEN = os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN")
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ".")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"{bot.user.name} is ready")

#---------------------------------------#
@bot.command(name = "bot_interact")
async def join(ctx, voice_channel: commands.VoiceChannelConverter):
    await voice_channel.connect()
    await ctx.send("-play (desired_song)")
    time.sleep(2)
    await ctx.send("-loop")

@bot.command(name = "leave")
async def leave(ctx):
    server = ctx.message.guild.voice_client
    await server.disconnect()
#---------------------------------------#

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Besides, I made it so full so you see specifically what I'm trying to do, which is my bot to get the attention of Groovy, and to tell Groovy, I want to play this song. Bear in mind I'm relatively new to python, I haven't used it too much. Thx in advance

Comment: Most bots dont allow interaction with other bots, I dont think this is possible especially with Groovy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bots are almost always designed to ignore any other bot's messages. Without this, the bot may go into an infinite loop.

Groovy does the exact same thing; it will ignore every other messages sent by bots.